# Best tutorial for ROS programming on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Raspberry pi and **Ubuntu mate** inside it.i installed ROS.but i havent find a proper  ROS-python programming tutorials on Rpi.Can you guys suggest me some ?How to learn to program ROS on RPI ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280148/best-tutorial-for-ros-programming-on-raspberry-pi-?/) by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2018-01-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-18**:
Is there a problem with the [`rospy` tutorials on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Tutorials)?

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-01-18**:
Is there any simple ROS-RPi Programs in python ?
for example Light blink,Ultrasonic sensors and  Rotary-encoders ?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-18**:
As this is HW-specific, there is (at least to my knowledge) no such tutorial. Check the Publisher/Subscriber tutorials on the ROS wiki, as well as a tutorial for how to "make a light blink" for the RPi (Google around), and try to bring them together (if you receive a message, toggle the light...)

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-01-18**:
ok.thanx you friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@melvinyesudas you can check Mastering Ros For Robotics Programming by Lentin Josph mainly chapter 7
these are in c but if you want in python look at these

https://www.intorobotics.com/ros-tutorials-start-working-arduino-raspberry-pi/

check this too :-

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=NtWQAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT158&lpg=PT158&dq=ros+on+rpi+python+with+led+blink&source=bl&ots=9zU2VuZn5u&sig=hy3SXcAfPKEiZJYUP_lArUZHxoM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWj6fssO3YAhWKnZQKHZkJAQgQ6AEIZDAI#v=onepage&q=ros%20on%20rpi%20python%20with%20led%20blink&f=false

---

Originally posted by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) with karma: 216 on 2018-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1